# Understanding the 'x to y' in the VBA Dim myArray(x to y) statement

Tags: arrays, vba

I have searched the web, Microsoft's site, vba help, but can't find a reference to what the '0 to 10' part of this dim statement means.

```
Dim myArray(0 to 10)
```

Can someone help clarify exactly is going on? I am suspecting it has to do with dimensioning a multidimensional array but I would like to understand what is happening under the covers or if I am even correct.

Edit:
Sorry, I started thinking about this question in the context of redimensioning, which is where I first saw the example, but then saw that its use was also for the initial dimensioning as well.

Comment: @Okuma.Scott: The linked question does not describe the "0 to 10".

Comment: @Walter Henze My mistake. I realized it the second after flagged too. REALLY wish there was a way to take back a flag in the first min or so. Plenty of people agree on meta.

Comment: I realize the way I originally wrote this question did not make clear what I was asking. I have edited it in an attempt to provide that clarity. I apologize for my pathetic excuse of a first attempt to ask my question.

Answer (score 1):

This statement is declaring an empty `variant` array of 11 items ( 0 to 10 ) called myArray.

It is a variant because is not specifically declared as any other type.

Comment: After you have declared it, you can use the variable like this: `myArray(0)="hello!"` and `myArray(10)=2.5`. If you use an index less than 0 or greater than 10 it will cause an error. If you access an element that has not been initialized (explicitly assigned a value) it will return "nothing". Note that VBA is a bit weird about the base of arrays - in many cases it ignores the lower bound of arrays...

Comment: How is this different from `dim myArr(10)`?

Comment: @Rob .. myArr(10) has only 10 elements .. 0 to 9 ..

Comment: Just to note, it's an array of Variants, not a Variant array. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa163618%28v=office.10%29.aspx

Comment: @matzone not necesarly, it depends on your Option Base setting, if it is one then you are correct, myArr(10) will have only 10 elements, the default `Option Base 0` will result in 11. It's always better to declare the lower bound

Answer (score 0):

http://excelvbatutor.com/vba_chp21.htm

The website has quite detailed explanation of arrays in VBA.

In brief,

`Dim myArray(0 to 10)` is creating an array with index 0 to 10 (i.e. 11 elements)

For what you mentioned about redimensioning, you should look for `redim` instead